# what is the best way to use same lib, helpers, etc in different CodeIgniter Projects?

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, architecture, project-management

I have a lot of codes in libraries, helpers, models of my old codeigniter projects.

I want to start a new project that I think I can use those codes without rewriting them. Also, when I want to update the codes in the libraries, helpers or models, I only have to update them once in one file. However if I copy and paste the file to the new project, I have to update each of them when I have an update in the code.

So how can I do this in best practice?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at theis article by Phil Sturgeon - in it he details a way to create a 'shared' folder, so that you can run multiple codeigniter installations from the same shared folder.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/136321/

Answer (score 1):

Since Codeigniter 2.0 you can share same system folder among many projects.  In previous versions you can do this with a little tweak.  So once you have a common system folder you can keep all you libraries and helpers here which can be used by all the projects.  There is no provision to have common models so either you can transform them to helper or library class, which actually makes sense.